# jquery validate - custom rule - dependency callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I really have no idea why my custom rule in jquery isnt working. all it is is looking for a substring in a text, making it required if it DOESNT appear, not required if it does. I am using the jquery validate library. I hope its something simple... please help!

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
$(function() {
    $("#frmUpdateCC").validate({
        errorContainer: "#updateProfileCC",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
        rules: {
            txtCardNo1: {
                required: true,
                creditcard: function() {
                    var str = $('#txtCardNo1').val();
        str = (str.indexOf("xxxxxx"));
        return (str != 6 );
                }
            }
            cboMonth1: "required",
            cboCard1: "required",

        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Ive tried using !== 6, !='6', and other variations thereof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `str.indexOf("xxxxxx")` is going to return the start position of `"xxxxxx"` in your string `str`.

So, if `str` contains `'xxxxxx'`, your statements would only evaluate as true if `'xxxxxx'` begins as position 6. Did you mean to test for str.length maybe?

Otherwise, why not simply do:

```
str = (str.indexOf("xxxxxx"));
    return (str === -1 );
```

Comment: I'll give that a try... Basically I need the statement to evaluate as false If that statement exists ( in the sixth position or any position ).... I've tried -1 but I'll give it another go.

Comment: that should work.  If the string is not found, then indexOf would be equal to -1...so, str === -1 would return true.  If the "xxxxxx" is found, then the indexOf will be greater than -1, so  str === -1 would return false.

Comment: You are most welcome. Sorry I hadn't gotten back to you before now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your callback function to be assigned to the "required" property, not the "creditcard" property:

```
required: function() { var str = .... }
```

Currently you have the required property hard-coded to true.

Comment: Nope I need it to only check for the credit card property If those Xs aren't there. It's always required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

```
creditcard: function() {
                    var str = $('#txtCardNo1').val();
        str = (str.indexOf("xxxxxx"));
       if (str > -1) {                                                                
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {                                
                            return false;
                        }
                }
```

i think the rule **credit card** will only support number format like **nnn-nnn-nnn**. So i think you have to add another rule according to your need, i mean **custom rule** .